# matching regex pattern with lambda inside a filter for RDD pyspark

Tags: regex, filter, rdd, pyspark

I have data in an RDD and it looks something like this:

```
['1,google.com',  
 '2,youtube.com',  
 '3,facebook.com',  
 '4,baidu.com',  
 '5,wikipedia.org']
```

I want to extract all urls that end with .com using rdd.filter.
I tried something like this:

```
top1m.filter(lambda x: x['_c1'].endswith('.com'))
```

This gave me a Py4JJavaError error because Python 3.6 does not work with the Spark session that I have running. I feel like there must be some better way to do it, especially using the regex. Please help! I am unsure about how to use the syntax.

Comment: Maybe `top1m.filter(top1m['_c1'].rlike('[.]com$'))`? Or, `top1m.filter('_c1' rlike '[.]com$')`?

Comment: The first one gives an error "RDD object is not subscriptable" and the second one is invalid syntax.